# Is there a way to implement Subresource Integrity Check for Next.js? Either Next 12, 13, or 14?

Tags: next.js, subresource-integrity

Enabling experimental sri module.

```
experimental: {
    sri: {
      algorithm: 'sha256'
    }
  },
```

It generates the subresource integrity manifest files, but doesn't inject the integrity attribute within the build.

We were expecting to see an integrity attribute within the script tag. For Example:

```
<script integrity="kjkdjkdjkjaaaldks="/>
```

but was getting within the built html

```
<script />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, unfortunately it is not possible to have SRI on the scripts that next js generated by itself. I [cite](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/fa935e5a3cd3553e3b2e21910d78a8a2fe836ab8/test/production/app-dir/subresource-integrity/subresource-integrity.test.ts#L148): "Currently webpack chunks loaded via flight runtime do not get integrity hashes."